# How do I transfer this c ++ for loop into java for loop

Tags: java, c++

I am a newbie C++ and I want to convert this line of for loop code into java version

```
for(;diff;diff++){
     do something here
}
```

diff is an integer type variable. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `diff` is it POD or a class? Is it signed or unsigned?

Comment: does `diff` start out negative? else the original loop will loop till INT_MAX, then loop around till `diff` is 0 - is that what happens? if not, then the condition to check should be `diff < 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that C allows an implicit conversion from int to boolean for the termination condition whereas Java doesn't. Try

```
for(; diff != 0; diff++)
{
```

which should be equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

In Java, unlike in C++, an integer is not automatically translated to a boolean expression. You have to write it like this in Java:

```
for ( ; diff != 0; diff++) {
    // do something here
}
```